# Filing 83(b) election as an international consultant?

Tags: united-states, contractor, compensation, 83b-election

I recently went from being an employee in a US company (while being in the US) to being a consultant for the same company (while working abroad in my home country of India). As part of my new compensation I was issued stocks.

Do I need to file 83(b) election even as an international consultant? Note that I've filed my US taxes in the past, and will file them again this year since I worked for 3 months of the current fiscal year before moving to my home country.

Does the answer to the question change if I intend to return to the US in the future and the stocks vest while i'm in the US?

Comment: Are you a US taxpayer?

Comment: @littleadv I've paid taxes in the US in the past, but for this financial year I will pay only for a few months but my primary tax filings will be abroad.

Comment: Yes it will depending on how long ur gone